# Website Editor for Simple Pages

Tags: html, web, css, development

I find myself in a situation where I'm aiming to create a simple website for a client. The website's purpose is to provide information about the client's business, without requiring any special functionality.

I'm quite familiar with Shopify and really appreciate its Customizer feature, which allows me to code sections and offer clients easy customization options. I'm wondering if there's a suitable tool for creating similar customizable websites that aren't for e-commerce.

Essentially, I'm looking for a tool that combines a code editor with a visual customizer and includes cloud storage for images. Any recommendations?

I don't like WordPress or any of the "no Code" pure Visual editors.

Comment: So you have (or will get) a web host to which you can push your own HTML files, right? If so, you are looking for a WYSIWYG+code HTML editor, I think.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I read it as something like WordPress with the option of editing the HTML and CSS directly.  And I doubt if it will exist.

Comment: Leon, please help us by clarifying. Thanks! :-)